# Order JCR nodes by hierarchy order

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

I have a list of nodes in Magnolia:

- /

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4

But when I put them in a loop, they're coming out in a random order:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page] WHERE ISCHILDNODE('/')
```

- 3
- 4
- 2
- 1

What do I need to specify in the `ORDER BY` clause for the nodes to be ordered the same way as the interface?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980029/jcr-sql2-result-query-order-as-in-jcr-browser

Comment: Or you can use old JCR SQL instead of JCR SQL2 - then the nodes come as they are ordered.