# Recursive search in JCR repo via java

Tags: java, search, recursion, jcr, jcr-sql2

I know how to search for something in the **[JCR](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/index.html)** via [JCR SQL2 queries](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html).

However, I would like to use Java in certain cases, using the [JCR API](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jcr-api.html): `javax.jcr.Node`, `javax.jcr.NodeIterator` and the like.

I'm afraid I will simply reinvent the wheel by coding my own.

Is there anything already available (`Gist`, `Github` or `else`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use for that [SlingQuery](https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Query). It's inspired by jQuery and follows it's syntax. You should use it only to search small number of nodes (in best case under 100), because traversal queries are slow.

**Edit**

Your example may be converted to the following SlingQueries (not tested):

```
SlingQuery.$(startResource).find("[name=teasers][title=awesome-teaser]")

SlingQuery.$(startResource).find("[name][controlName]")
```

SlingQuery is part of [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-query.html) since a while, that's why the github repository seems to be abandoned.

Note: You can static import the Dollar sign and drop the static access over SlingQuery in your syntax such as $(resource).find("...");

Comment: Could you convert one of the method examples of my answer into a SlingQuery example?

Comment: SlingQuery looks rather "quiet". Not sure if I'd like to rely on such project. See https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Query/graphs/contributors

Comment: Please see my edit above. The SlingQuery project is part of Apache Sling now. I converted also your examples to SlingQueries, but I haven't tested them. The syntax is exactly as the jQuery syntax. I'm using the project in a couple customer projects and it works stable, no worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [ItemVisitor](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/ItemVisitor.html) to recursively traverse the repository collecting all items that match your criteria along the way.

E.g. printing out all properties of type `Long`:

```
Node root = session.getRootNode();
root.accept(new ItemVisitor() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Property property) throws RepositoryException {
        if (!property.isMultiple() && property.getType() == PropertyType.LONG) {
             System.out.println(property.getName() + " = " + property.getLong());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Node node1) throws RepositoryException {
        NodeIterator children = node1.getNodes();
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            visit(children.nextNode());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own implementations.

Feel free to improve or add comments for potential improvements.

---

#### Further info

Java is probably NOT the most efficient way of searching through the JCR, so mind the performance hit (vs using `JCR SQL2`).

However, there are cases where using JCR SQL2 will be rather annoying. For instance: [JCR SQL2 - result query order as in JCR browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980029/jcr-sql2-result-query-order-as-in-jcr-browser)

I'd recommend launching your search as low as possible in the tree.

---

#### Solution

Read the comments above each method to find our more.

```
package com.nameoforganization.jcr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class JcrSearchUtils {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JcrUtil.class);

    /*
     * Recursive search in JCR tree: properties matching values
     * Parameters:
     *  - node: node to start the search from
     *  - propertyValueConditions: properties searched along with the value expected for it
     *  - searchResults: set this to null when launching the search
     */
    public static ArrayList<Node> searchRecursivelyPropMatchVal(Node node, HashMap<String, String> propertyValueConditions, ArrayList<Node> searchResults) {
        if(searchResults == null){
            searchResults = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }
        try{    
            NodeIterator list = node.getNodes();

            while(list.hasNext())   {

                Node currentSubNode = list.nextNode();
                Boolean hasAllRequiredPropsAndVals = true;

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertyValueConditions.entrySet()) {
                    String propertyName = entry.getKey();
                    Object searchedValue = entry.getValue();
                    if ( !currentSubNode.hasProperty(propertyName) || !currentSubNode.getProperty(propertyName).getString().equals(searchedValue) ){
                        hasAllRequiredPropsAndVals = false;
                    }                   
                }
                if ( hasAllRequiredPropsAndVals ){
                    searchResults.add(currentSubNode);
                }

                searchRecursivelyPropMatchVal(currentSubNode, propertyValueConditions, searchResults);
            }

            return searchResults;
        } catch (RepositoryException rpe){
            log.info("Recursive search in JCR tree (properties matching values) via JCR API failed");
        }
        return null;
    }


    /*
     * Recursive search in JCR tree: required properties present 
     * Parameters:
     *  - node: node to start the search from
     *  - propertyValueConditions: properties searched along with the value expected for it
     *  - searchResults: set this to null when launching the search
     */
    public static ArrayList<Node> searchRecursivelyPropPres(Node node, ArrayList<String> propertyPresConditions, ArrayList<Node> searchResults) {
        if(searchResults == null){
            searchResults = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }
        try{    
            NodeIterator list = node.getNodes();

            while(list.hasNext())   {

                Node currentSubNode = list.nextNode();
                Boolean hasAllRequiredProperties = true;

                for (String propertyName : propertyPresConditions) {
                    if ( !currentSubNode.hasProperty(propertyName) ){
                        hasAllRequiredProperties = false;
                    }
                }
                if( hasAllRequiredProperties ){
                    searchResults.add(currentSubNode);
                }

                searchRecursivelyPropPres(currentSubNode, propertyPresConditions, searchResults);
            }

            return searchResults;
        } catch (RepositoryException rpe){
            log.info("Recursive search in JCR tree (required properties present) via JCR API failed");
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

---

#### Usage of first utility method

```
    /*
     *  Search nodes with properties:
     *  "name" having value "teasers"
     *  "title" having value "awesome-teaser"
     */
    // Node startingNode = set this yourself :)
    HashMap<String, String> propertyValueConditions = new HashMap<String, String>();
    propertyValueConditions.put("name", "teasers");
    propertyValueConditions.put("title", "awesome-teaser");
    ArrayList<Node> nodesFound = JcrUtil.searchRecursivelyPropMatchVal(startingNode, propertyValueConditions, null);
```

#### Usage of second utility method

```
    /*
     *  Search nodes having properties "name" and "controlName"
     */
    // Node startingNode = set this yourself :)
    ArrayList<String> propertyPresConditions = new ArrayList<String>();
    propertyPresConditions.add("name");
    propertyPresConditions.add("controlName");
    ArrayList<Node> nodesFound = JcrUtil.searchRecursivelyPropPres(startingNode, propertyPresConditions, null);
```

---

#### Resources:

- [JCRUtils.java - API doc - Apache Jackrabbit 2.0.0 API](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html)
- [Node.java - API doc - *Adobe's Content Repository for Java 2.0*](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html)
- [Session.java - API doc - *Adobe's Content Repository for Java 2.0*](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html)